# Semaphore latency faster than expected - why?

Tags: c++, concurrency

Acquisition of a semaphore is done by blocking. According to the internet and clockres, the interrupt frequency / timer interval on Windows shouldn't be under 0.5ms. The program below measures the time between the release and acquisition of a semaphore in different threads. I would not expect this to be faster than 0.5ms, yet I reliably get results of ~0.017ms. (Curiously with a high standard deviation of +- 100%)

Either my measurement code is wrong, or my understanding of how semaphores work is. Which is it? Code without the boring code to calculate mean and standard deviation:

```
namespace {
   std::binary_semaphore semaphore{ 0 };
   std::atomic<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point> t1;
}

auto acquire_and_set_t1() {
   semaphore.acquire(); // this is being measured
   t1.store(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
}

auto measure_semaphore_latency() -> double {
   std::jthread j(acquire_and_set_t1);
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms); // To make sure thread is running

   // Signal thread and start timing
   const auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   semaphore.release();

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms); // To make sure thread is done writing t1

   const double ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1.load() - t0).count() / 1'000'000.0;
   return ms;
}

auto main() -> int {
   std::vector<double> runtimes;
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      runtimes.emplace_back(measure_semaphore_latency());

   const auto& [mean, relative_std] = get_mean_and_std(runtimes);
   std::cout << std::format("mean: {:.3f} ms, +- {:.2f}%\n", mean, 100.0 * relative_std);
}
```

edit: sources for windows timer resolution is https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/ and [ClockRes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/clockres)

Comment: According to the internet, the Earth is flat and vaccines are 5G mobile tracking devices. What are your specific sources?

Comment: The usual answer to questions of this type is to say - MS-Windows is not a realtime OS and the OS scheduler is a blackbox. `semaphore` may or may not suspend in the kernel; they may use hard-loops or a a combination of both.

Comment: You aren't measuring the time it takes to acquire a semaphore. You are measuring the time it takes to `sleep_for(5ms)`. `semaphore.acquire()` call is not even between `t1` and `t0`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `.acquire()` is between t0 and t1 if I'm not mistaken? And that's what I'm measuring.

Comment: Other usual caveat: You should be performing benchmarks using a benchmarking library. There's a lot of nitty-gritty stuff that can interfere with results.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, what you are actually measuring is "time to spin up a new thread" + "time to call semaphore.acquire()" - "time to execute `sleep_for(5ms)`". I expect the first and last are orders of magnitude larger than the second - you mostly measure thread creation and the accuracy of `sleep_for`

Comment: @Frank oftentimes yes, but in this case I think this is the best (transparent) solution.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the comments were wrong, but the code was not. t0 is set. Then comes `.release()` which triggers acquire() and t1. There's another wait in the main thread to make sure this goes through. I believe this is correct.

Comment: I updated the comment, before seeing your response. The bottom line, you are not really measuring `semaphore.acquire()`; this is a tiny part of what's happening.

Comment: What else am I measuring between t0 and t1? Even if there was more: I'm wondering why the time is so small, not why it's big.

Comment: Apparently, spinning up a thread takes approximately 5ms (or rather, approximately how long `sleep_for(5ms)` actually sleeps - I suspect it sleeps for at least 15ms, one clock tick). You are subtracting two large numbers that just happen to be close to each other.

Comment: I really can't follow. The first sleep is exactly to make sure there's enough time for the thread to spool up _before_ any measurements are taken. I've confirmed this in the debugger.

Comment: What makes you think spinning up a thread takes exactly 5ms, and not one and not 50? Sleep longer, and your timing will be negative - would you then say that acquiring a semaphore takes negative time, that it magically sets the clock back?

Comment: I'm confident that it takes less than 5ms. 1) From measuring 2) Seeing that the result is invariant under different wait times, as expected. However feel free to add a 0 to all wait times.

Comment: Let me put it this way. You have an arbitrary constant in your code. Changing this constant would drastically alter the measured times (see what you get if you sleep for `50ms` instead). Yet this constant has nothing to do with the thing that is supposedly being measured. Ergo, you are not measuring the right thing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You've repeated this statement multiple times even with contrary evidence. Feel free to set that constant to anything you like (while still reasonable). It doesn't influence the result.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm stupid. Ignore everything I said; I misunderstood what you were doing. You are measuring the time for `release` on one thread to get noticed and unblock `acquire` on the other thread.

Comment: Yes exactly! all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion is coming from the faulty assumption that this comes into play:

> According to the internet and clockres, the interrupt frequency / timer interval on Windows shouldn't be under 0.5ms.

Preemptive / timer-based scheduling does not have to be the only opportunity for an OS to assign threads to CPU cores. Explicit/Manual signalling can bypass it.

You can think of it as `std::binary_semaphore::release()` triggering an immediate partial run of the scheduler only targeting threads that happen to have a `std::binary_semaphore::acquire()` on the same semaphore.

This is what's happening here. The `measure_semaphore_latency()` thread is being woken up and *potentially* assigned to a CPU core immediately as the `release()` call is made, without waiting for the next scheduling "cycle".

It's still not guaranteed that the OS will choose to preempt anything for that just-woken-up thread. This is where the high standard deviation you are seeing comes from: The thread either gets immediate CPU time, or gets it at a later scheduling cycle, there's no in-between.

As to why I can be so confident that this is the case in your test: With a bit of debugging and symbols loading, we can get the following call stacks:

On the acquire side:

```
    ntdll.dll!00007fffa4510764()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!00007fffa44d379d()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!00007fffa44d3652()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!00007fffa44d3363()    Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!00007fffa225ce9f()   Unknown
>   msvcp140d_atomic_wait.dll!`anonymous namespace'::__crtWaitOnAddress(volatile void * Address, void * CompareAddress, unsigned __int64 AddressSize, unsigned long dwMilliseconds) Line 174    C++
    msvcp140d_atomic_wait.dll!__std_atomic_wait_direct(const void * _Storage, void * _Comparand, unsigned __int64 _Size, unsigned long _Remaining_timeout) Line 234 C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::_Atomic_wait_direct<unsigned char,char>(const std::_Atomic_storage<unsigned char,1> * const _This, char _Expected_bytes, const std::memory_order _Order) Line 491  C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::_Atomic_storage<unsigned char,1>::wait(const unsigned char _Expected, const std::memory_order _Order) Line 829 C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::counting_semaphore<1>::acquire() Line 245  C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!acquire_and_set_t1() Line 17    C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::invoke<void (__cdecl*)(void)>(void(*)() && _Obj) Line 1586 C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void)>,0>(void * _RawVals) Line 56  C++
    ucrtbased.dll!00007fff4c7b542c()    Unknown
    kernel32.dll!00007fffa2857034() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!00007fffa44c2651()    Unknown
```

On the release side:

```
    ntdll.dll!00007fffa44d2550()    Unknown 
>   msvcp140d_atomic_wait.dll!`anonymous namespace'::__crtWakeByAddressSingle(void * Address) Line 179  C++
    msvcp140d_atomic_wait.dll!__std_atomic_notify_one_direct(const void * _Storage) Line 251    C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::_Atomic_storage<unsigned char,1>::notify_one() Line 833    C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::counting_semaphore<1>::release(const __int64 _Update) Line 232 C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!measure_semaphore_latency() Line 29 C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!main() Line 36  C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!invoke_main() Line 79   C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 288   C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!__scrt_common_main() Line 331   C++
    ConsoleApplication2.exe!mainCRTStartup(void * __formal) Line 17 C++
    kernel32.dll!00007fffa2857034() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!00007fffa44c2651()    Unknown
```

Poking around the code of `__crtWakeByAddressSingle()`, and `__crtWaitOnAddress()` [(see on github)](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/6d2f8b0ed88ea6cba26cc2151f47f678442c1663/stl/src/atomic_wait.cpp#L167)  we find that the invoked kernel functions are  `WaitOnAddress()` [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress) and `WakeByAddressSingle()` [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-wakebyaddresssingle).

From this documentation, we find our confirmation in the remarks section of `WaitOnAddress()`:

> WaitOnAddress does not interfere with the thread scheduler.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that, that's cool. If you don't mind: Why does it *not* interfere with the scheduler when you initially made a point that (the release) does?

Comment: @Basti, I did say "think of it as". release doesn't *really* interfere with the scheduler, it just happens to do work that is similar to it.